# How to achieve EC2 high availability while preferring the instance launch into a specific Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**I am looking for how to specify the zone I want to deploy to in a single instance deployment, with autoscaling, while also having automatic failover to another zone -- Do any options exist to achieve this?**

---

### More context

Due to how reserved instances are linked to a single availability zone (AZ), we find it to be a good strategy (from an "ease of management"/simplicity perspective), when buying reserved instances for our dev environment, to buy them all in a single zone and then launch all dev instances in that single zone. (In production, we buy across zones and run with autoscale groups that specify to deploy across all zones).

**I am looking for how to:**

1. Specify the AZ that I want an instance to be deployed to, so that I can leverage the reserved instances that are tied to a single (and consistent) AZ.

**while also having**

2. The ability to failover to an alternate zone if the primary zone fails (yes, you will pay more money until you move the reserved instances, but presumably the failover is temporary e.g. 8 hours, and you can fail back once the zone is back online).

The issue is that I can see how you can achieve 1 or 2, but not 1 and 2 at the same time.

To achieve 1, I would specify a single subnet (and therefore AZ) to deploy to, as part of the autoscale group config.

To achieve 2, I would specify more than one subnet in different AZs, while keeping the min/max/capacity setting at 1. If the AZ that the instance non-deterministically got deployed to fails, the autoscale group will spin up an instance in the other AZ.

One cannot do 1 and 2 together to achieve a preference for which zone an autoscale group of min/max/capacity of 1 gets deployed to while also having automatic failover if the zone the server is in fails; they are competing solutions.

Comment: I would love this. Last time I talked to AWS support, the answer was that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution uses all AWS mechanisms to achieve the desired effect:**

1. Launch the instance into the preferred zone by specifying that zone's subnet in the 1st autoscale group's config; **this** **group's min/max/capacity is set to 1/1/1**.
2. Create a second autoscale group with the same launch config as the 1st, **but this other autoscale group is set to a min/max/desired of 0/1/0;** this group should be configured with the subnets in every available zone in the region except the one specified in the 1st autoscale group.
3. Associate the 2nd autoscale group with the same ELB that is associated with the 1st autoscale group.
4. Set up a CloudWatch alarm that triggers on the unhealthy host alarm for #1's autoscale group; have the alarm change the #2 autoscale group's to a min/max/desired of 1/1/1. (As well as send out a notification so that you know this happened).

If you don't expect to get unhealthy host alarms except in the cases where there is an actual host failure or if the AZ goes down -- which is true in our case -- this is a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already figured out, (as of mid-2015) that's not possible. Auto-scaling doesn't have the concept of failover, strictly speaking. It expects you to provide more than one AZ and machines enough in each one if you want to have high availability. If you don't, then you aren't going to get it.

The only possible workaround I can imagine for this is setting up a watchdog yourself which changes the auto-scaling group's subnet once an AZ becomes unavailable. Not so hard to do, but no so reliable as well.